# How to get/catch Http response message on another port

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, service

I'm writing simple asp.net web api project. In my service scenario, we need to send request on specific port (for example 8080) and we want to get or catch this api's response messages on different port (for example 8090), Is this mirror scenario available for .net ? How can i control this pipeline on asp.net web api ?

Comment: You can't send a message unless a connection is made.  So a new connection has to be established to use a different port number.  Protocols that use multiple ports have a process for opening additional connections using different port numbers.  Then once the new connection is established message can be sent.

Comment: @jdweng how can i do that at code behind ? Is it possible in c# ?

Comment: Your request on 8080 will have a synchronous response on that connection in any case, even if it's just a 200 (okay). Why do you need (what I assume is) the rich response to come in on a different port?

Comment: I need a rich response because, we want to do transactions on main port and we need to logging detailed responses on another port. we have got big traffic on server and mirroring is look likes most acceptable solution for us.

Comment: The client can open up a listener on port 8090 before connecting to the server using 8080.  Then when the server accepts the connection to port 8080 the server can make a connection back to the client on port 8090.  Normally when you have multiple ports the main/initial port is a command channel and the additional ports are for data transfers.  So the main port you can create a command language for client and server to communicate.  One of the commands can be to open new connections.